# Does an antenna have to be impedance matched to its transmitter circuit or the transmission line from it?

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching

I am still very new to RF and I am trying to understand Impedance matching, so my question could be stupid.

I have already learned the basics of it, I know how to use Smith charts, which components to use to match it etc. But one question has risen up:

Reading from *most* sources, matching must be made between the source and the load (antenna). However, reading on [antenna-theory.com](https://www.antenna-theory.com/tutorial/smith/smithchart5.php) (which is the source I learned nearly all I know about Impedance matching) it says this: [image]

In all examples I have seen on the matching series on the website, the impedance used in the Normalized impedance formula was always 50 ohms (coaxial cable I suppose)

And that's the thing which is confusing me. I am going to try a RF project and I just can't get over this thing.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, nothing has to be matched to anything else. And for perfect matching, everything has to be matched to everything else.

Comment: What's the RF project you are planning to work on?

Comment: @vu2nan I wanted to make a half wave dipole to catch one certain AM station. Though none of the radios I have at home go so high on the frequency band. So I decided to see how difficult of a circuit the receiver could be, thinking that I may just copy some circuit and use it without understanding (something I don't like to do.) But I came across a video series, where a guy was explaining such one, an it is very simple - just LC oscillator, diode for rectification, Capacitor to smooth the wave and a resistor (whose function I didn't quite understand). So now I am trying to understand the rest.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 - Hi! Thanks for the info. Is that AM station on medium wave or shortwave? What's the frequency? Are you trying to build a crystal radio or a powered one?

Comment: @vu2nan The station is 126 Mhz. The design I was looking at didn't include any amplifiers, but I am not sure if one will be needed. Just so you know, although I marked the answer I will be grateful if you keep on helping me.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 - Sure! So your project is to build an aviation band receiver. If you're living very close to an airport, a crystal radio, followed by an audio amplifier, may work. http://www.vk2zay.net/article/247 or http://techlib.com/electronics/aircraft.htm. For a distance of up to 25 km from the airport, a down converter, in conjunction with a HF receiver used as a tuneable IF / audio amplifier, would work quite well with a ¼ λ ground plane antenna. Transmissions from planes, coming in to land, could even overload your receiver. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEiyF6e-nJI.

Comment: @vu2nan Thanks for the great resources. The only thing is that im not just new to rf, but to electronics in general so those circuits seem very difficult for me to fully understand. Ill have to have a hard look on them. But nevertheless, Thank you.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 - Anytime! For a start you should build a fox-hole radio or a crystal radio to receive nearby medium wave AM radio stations. Here's a great resource.                                                                              
https://www.mikroe.com/ebooks/radio-receivers-from-crystal-set-to-stereo/the-simplest-amplified-radio-receiver. Have fun!

Comment: @vu2nan That seems like just the thing I need! By the way, if I come across anything that I don't understand would you mind if I contact you somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does an antenna have to be impedance matched to its transmitter
> circuit or the transmission line from it?*

If the t-line is short i.e. less than one-tenth of a wavelength of the carrier frequency, then match antenna to the transmitter.

Else, match the antenna to the t-line using an L-pad, T-pad or Pi network (or combinations) if the antenna is not particularly close to a resistive impedance.

<sub>Normally there's no great need to match the transmitter to the t-line although this is quite often done.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does the same apply if the antenna is receiving?

Comment: The receiver input impedance needs to be matched to the t-line.

Comment: So if I take it right, if my antenna has, lets say 75 ohm impedance, the total impedance of the whole receiver circuit (after calculating it) should ideally be 75 ohm too?

Comment: Not quite. A 75 ohm **receiving** antenna can feed a t-line of 50 ohm but, the receiver needs to be nominally 50 ohm to avoid disruptive reflections. Reflections occur on things that transport signals a distance and they occur initially on the output of that signal transportation mechanism. It's not ideal to do this of course - the preference is to match everything AND, matching everything is usually so easy to do.

Comment: I am starting to understand it well. I just have 2 more questions:
1. In the last example you gave, does the antenna need something to match to the t-line, or it can just be connected straight to it, the only "matching" being the one on the receiver side?
2. A stupid one but it bothers me - when matching, why is complex impedance (R + jX) always used, instead of the one, calculated with Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: (1) It's best to match the antenna to the t-line to avoid odd-shaped looking antenna gain patterns but, it isn't a necessity. (2) When matching to a t-line at RF frequencies, the t-line impedance looks purely resistive hence it's more useful to use a complex identity for an antenna's impedance because it's easier to figure out what coupling network components make the best impedance converter (from antenna to t-line).

Comment: I appreciate your time and patience, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Antenna, transmission line, transmitter/receiver don't **need** to be matched. A better question would be 'what are the consequences of any degree of mismatch?'

Mismatch causes signal reflections, which create a loss of signal reaching the far end. For a transmitter, the loss reduces the available power to the antenna. For a receiver, the effect of the loss is to increase its noise figure.

This mismatch loss is a function of cable length and frequency, making it difficult to predict performance. In a properly matched system, varying the length of cable, or the frequency by a small amount, does not affect the loss significantly.

Mismatch causes signal reflections, which add to the forward signal to create antinodes of higher voltage and current. For a particularly fragile or powerful transmitter, the extra voltage can damage the transmitter components, or even cause sparks on the transmission line. Many transmitters are specified to operate into a match no worse than some limit. If a transmitter is safe to operate into a short or open, you can bet that will be prominent on the data sheet.